# Removing all child element except <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove all child of an element except `<a>` tag, i use

```
  $("#tagId").children().remove();
```

but it remove all of the children, how can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `not` to exclude the anchor tags

`$("#tagId").children().not('a').remove();`

Comment: Glad to help. If this resolved your issue please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a selector to exclude `a`:

```js
$("#b").click(function() {
  $("#tagID").children(":not(a)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tagID">
  <span>This SPAN should be removed</span><br>
  <a href="#">This A should be kept</a><br>
  <div>This DIV should be removed</div>
</div>
<button id="b">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution that does not require jQuery:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container')

Array.from(container.children).filter(function(child) {
  return !(child instanceof HTMLAnchorElement)
}).forEach(function(child) {
  container.removeChild(child)
})
```